# Cross-module variable assigning in python

Tags: python, variables, import, module

Is there any way to somehow import a module, assign a variable in it, then use that variable in the program I imported with? I've probably explained that badly, for example

foo.py =

```
def main():
   x = 1
```

then, in another program,

```
import foo
foo.main()
print(x)
```

This, of course, doesn't work, is there
any way to pull this off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example you give, there is no `x` ... by the time you get back to try to `print` it. Its gone out of scope.

You do have some options, one of which is to return it:

foo.py =

```
def main():
   x = 1
   return x
```

And then elsewhere:

```
import foo
x = foo.main()
print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

@quamrana covers the sensible way to do this - with return values - but you can also straight-up use global variables. Say, we have two source files:

`foo.py`:

```
x = 0

def main():
    global x
    x = 1
```

and 
`bar.py`:

```
import foo
print(foo.x) # should print 0
foo.main()
print(foo.x) # should print 1
```

The `global` keyword in `foo.py`'s `main()` function is necessary to make sure that `x` is perceived as a global variable (belonging to the module `foo`) rather than a local variable (belonging to the function `main()`).

Then, in `bar.py`, we have to address `x` as `foo.x`, because `x` belongs to `foo`. You could also use named imports to circumvent that:

```
from foo import x, main
print(x) # should print 0
main()
print(x) # should print 1
```

Comment: I'm not sure your last block of code will work. The `x` that you import is a new local variable which is unaffected by `x = 1` in `foo.py`. You *should* see `0` then `0` again. Go with the first way: `foo.x`!